# jQuery and ASP.NEt MVC validation: Prevent validation on server

Tags: jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-3

I have model that looks like this:

```
public class Lesson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Naam voor de les is verplicht")]
    [Display(Name="Naam")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tijd is verplicht")]
    [Display(Name="Tijd")]
    public string Time { get; set; }

    //Prijs is default exclusief BTW
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Prijs is verplicht")]
    [Display(Name="Prijs (excl btw)")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Maximum aantal leerlingen")]
    public int MaxStudents { get; set; }
}
```

And a create view that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "gt-form-text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Time)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Time, new { @class = "gt-form-text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { @class = "gt-form-text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
     </div>
     <div>
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaxStudents)
     </div>
     <div>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MaxStudents, 
             new { @class = "gt-form-text" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaxStudents)
     </div>
 </div>
```

In the `Application_Start()` method I set [`DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidatorprovider.addimplicitrequiredattributeforvaluetypes%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to false.

`MaxStudents` is nullable and not required, nevertheless, if `MaxStudents` is null, the `Modelstate` is not valid `(ModelState.IsValid = false)`.

My errormessage is not shown, instead of that I get the errormessage is `A value is required`.

What can I do to get `ModelState.IsValid` to be true?

Comment: I just made the MaxStudents a nullable int and this works fine. But i'm still curious why my ModelState is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone shared this with me, and I'll pass it on in case it helps. Sometimes those validation errors get swallowed up and are hard to find. When I was having a similar issue, I added this code to my ActionResult (HttpPost) and it got me right to the error in question.

```
            try
        {
            db.Entry(myModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }           // }
```